# Hibernate Reactive : Session is closed and times out in scheduler

Tags: java, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-reactive, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

I'm currently working on a scheduler to change the status(Enum) in my base every 15 seconds using @ReactiveTransactional and throws "Session is closed" and then it runs my code for just one time. I tried it with just @Transactinal too (although it's not the right method) and it seems to be working until it reaches the fourth loop. Personally i think this could be an annotiation problem, because @ReactiveTransactional is supposed to handle the sessions by its own(I'm new to quarkus so if i'm wrong i'd love you to correct me ). Please take a look <3 .

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ActivateRequestContext
class EmployeeStatusChangeScheduler(
    private val repository: EmployeeRepository ) {

    var currentStatus: Status = Status.WORKING
    var changedStatus: Status = Status.NOT_WORKING

    @ReactiveTransactional
    @Scheduled(every = "10s")
    fun changeStatus(): Uni<Void> {
        currentStatus = if (currentStatus == Status.WORKING) Status.NOT_WORKING else Status.WORKING //working
        changedStatus = if (changedStatus == Status.WORKING) Status.NOT_WORKING else Status.WORKING //not-working
        return repository.update("status=?1 where status=?2", changedStatus, currentStatus)
            .onItem()
            .invoke { it ->
                if (it != 0) Log.info("[***] Status changed to [$changedStatus] for $it Employees")
                else Log.info("[---] There was no change in Employees for status...Please take a look")
            }
            .onItem()
            .ignore()
            .andSwitchTo(Uni.createFrom().voidItem())
    }

}
```

**The stack Trace(big one)**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HR000060: Session is closed
        at org.hibernate.reactive.pool.impl.ProxyConnection.withConnection(ProxyConnection.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.pool.impl.ProxyConnection.commitTransaction(ProxyConnection.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.pool.BatchingConnection.commitTransaction(BatchingConnection.java:194)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionImpl$Transaction.commit(MutinySessionImpl.java:471)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.impl.MutinySessionImpl$Transaction.lambda$executeInTransaction$2(MutinySessionImpl.java:454)
        at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualSupplier.get(SlowContextualSupplier.java:21)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnItem.lambda$call$3(UniOnItem.java:99)
        at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnItem.lambda$call$2(UniOnItem.java:79)
        at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualFunction.apply(SlowContextualFunction.java:21)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:68)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnCancellationCall$UniOnCancellationCallProcessor.onItem(UniOnCancellationCall.java:52)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onItem(UniOperatorProcessor.java:46)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:63)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:883)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2251)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:143)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:51)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage.subscribe(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:35)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:63)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:883)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2251)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:143)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:51)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage.subscribe(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:35)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.access$100(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:26)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemConsume$UniOnItemComsumeProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemConsume.java:43)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOperatorProcessor.onItem(UniOperatorProcessor.java:46)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromCompletionStage$CompletionStageUniSubscription.forwardResult(UniCreateFromCompletionStage.java:63)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.util.async.impl.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.unroll(AsyncTrampoline.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.util.async.impl.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.lambda$unroll$0(AsyncTrampoline.java:126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.util.async.impl.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.unroll(AsyncTrampoline.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.reactive.util.async.impl.AsyncTrampoline$TrampolineInternal.lambda$unroll$0(AsyncTrampoline.java:126)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Completabl.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at io.vertx.core.Future.lambda$toCompletionStage$2(Future.java:360)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:60)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
        at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.QueryResultBuilder.tryComplete(QueryResultBuilder.java:102)
        at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.QueryResultBuilder.tryComplete(QueryResultBuilder.java:35)
        at io.vertx.core.Promise.complete(Promise.java:66)
        at io.vertx.core.Promise.handle(Promise.java:51)
        at io.vertx.core.Promise.handle(Promise.java:29)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:86)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.execute(DuplicatedContext.java:163)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.emitSuccess(FutureBase.java:51)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:211)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.tryComplete(PromiseImpl.java:23)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.onSuccess(PromiseImpl.java:49)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:41)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.future.PromiseImpl.handle(PromiseImpl.java:23)
        at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.command.CommandResponse.fire(CommandResponse.java:46)
        at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.handleMessage(SocketConnectionBase.java:287)
        at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.PgSocketConnection.handleMessage(PgSocketConnection.java:97)
        at io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.lambda$init$0(SocketConnectionBase.java:100)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:55)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.emit(ContextBase.java:239)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.NetSocketImpl.handleMessage(NetSocketImpl.java:394)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:155)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgEncoder.lambda$write$0(PgEncoder.java:98)
        at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgCommandCodec.handleReadyForQuery(PgCommandCodec.java:139)
        at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.decodeReadyForQuery(PgDecoder.java:237)
        at io.vertx.pgclient.impl.codec.PgDecoder.channelRead(PgDecoder.java:96)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```